# Retrieve specific files in nested subfolder, without run listdir() multiple times

Tags: python

I have 42 folders, each contain a file that I need, and a folder, which has a name that is the same of the parent folder, minus a prefix, which contain another file that I need:

```
XXXXX_foldername
    foldername
        file.abc
    file.xyz
```

At the moment I am using os.listdir(); although to get to the file.abc, I need to make 2 pass, because in the first pass I get my `XXXXX_foldername` for each of my 42 folders, so I can acquire my `file.xyz`. Then I have to make the second pass for the `foldername`, to retrieve the `file.abc. This repeated N times, for as many folders I have.

```
def scan_folders(self):
    directory = "/Users/myuser/data"
    # This give me all 42 folders names
    folders_list = os.listdir(directory)
    for item in folders_list:
        # yet another listdir to get the xyz file
        xyz_file = "\n".join(s for s in os.listdir(directory + "/" + item) if "xyz".lower() in s.lower())
        print(xyz_file)
        # this give me the name of the sub-folder
        sub_folder_name = item[6:]
        # And another listdir to get the abc file
        abc_file = "\n".join(s for s in os.listdir(directory + "/" + item + "/" + sub_folder_name) if "abc".lower() in s.lower())
        print(abc_file)
```

I have to run listdir 2 times to get 2 filenames; is there a better and more efficient way, to find a file, without run the listdir so often? It is not a big deal for 42 folders, but I am planning to scan a folder that contains GB and GB of data, in multiple folders (where the XXXXX is an incremental integer).

Comment: What about [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)?

Comment: Well, isn't walk slower, since it call behind the scene listdir() plus stats()?

Comment: Off the top of my head I've no idea whether it's faster or not, have you tried it? Was it fast enough?

Comment: To be honest I didn't try, since if it is calling what I am calling already, plus it add an extra operation, it can't be faster than listdir() itself, isn't it? I never used it, so I am exploring the advantage of walk, chaging the logic in my code

Comment: So are you having 30,000 folders? Or just big files?